# using xpath simple xml with google contacts api?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm using google contacts api and php to parse an xml like so:

```
$req = new Google_HttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
$val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody());
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

  $output_array = array();
  foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    foreach ($entry->xpath('gd:email') as $email) {
      $output_array[] = array(
        (string)$entry->title, 
        //THIS DOESNT WORK WHY??
        (string)$entry->attributes()->href, 
        //
       (string)$email->attributes()->address);

    }
  }
```

This returns:

```
[1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "LOREM IPSUM"
    [1]=>
    string(0) ""
    [2]=>
    string(28) "hogash.themeforest@gmail.com"
  }
```

the raw xml response is like so:

```
     <entry>
      <id>http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/EMAIL/base/e29c818b038d9a</id>
      <updated>2012-08-28T21:52:20.909Z</updated>
      <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind" term="http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact" />
      <title type="text">Lorem ipsum</title>
      <link rel="http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo" type="image/*" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/EMAIL/e29c818b038d9a/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg" />
      <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/EMAIL/full/e29c818b038d9a" />
      <link rel="edit" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/EMAIL/full/e29c818b038d9a/1346190740909001" />
      <gd:email rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other" address="hogash.themeforest@gmail.com" primary="true" />
   </entry>
```

How do i get at the image url aswell as the contact name and title?

Comment: You're trying to get the `href` from the three `<link>` tags?

Comment: just the image type="image/*" is enough but all three would be nice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to access the `<link>` elements, but are accessing the `attributes()` of `$entry`, which does not have `href` attributes.

```
// Doesn't have an href attribute...
(string)$entry->attributes()->href
```

Instead, get the `link` elements and loop over them to create an array of `href`.

```
  $output_array = array();
  foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    // Initialize an array out here.
    $entry_array = array();

    // Get the title and link attributes (link as an array)
    $entry_array['title'] = (string)$entry->title;

    $entry_array['hrefs'] = array();
    foreach($entry->link as $link) {
      // append each href in a loop
      $entry_array['hrefs'][] = $link->attributes()->href;
    }

    // If there are never more than 1 email, you don't need a loop here.
    foreach ($entry->xpath('gd:email') as $email) {
      // Get the email
      $entry_array['email'] = (string)$email->attributes()->address
    }
    // Append your array to the larger output
    $output_array[] = $entry_array;
  }

  // Look at the result
  print_r($output_array);
```

Comment: You are a genius thank you i've been fighting this API for a day and a half now and it's driving me mad...

Comment: Nice, any idea how to get the image?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet The image is in a `<link>` tag should be inside the `foreach ($entry->link...)` loop. To find out which it is while looping, use something like `if ($link->attributes()->type == "image/*")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand, this is what `$link` dumps `object(SimpleXMLElement)#30 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["rel"]=>
    string(38) "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other"
    ["address"]=>
    string(22) "rocio_deia@hotmail.com"
    ["primary"]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
}`

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet [SimpleXMLElement objects](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) implement `var_dump()` to display some of the information contained within. It has an @attributes key, so you may access `$link['@attributes']['address']` to get that email address. In my example, I used the `attributes()` method instead to get the href and type from `$link`.

Comment: Can you please help me out how to show the image of contacts via this api :  SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rel] => http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo
            [type] => image/*
            [href] => https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/test@domain.com/1d90bd968bb433ec
        )

) I am getting this type of response for each link tag, but dont know how to fetch the image using this..

Comment: `@attributes` is a property (an array), and `href` is a key of that array, so `$that_object->{"@attributes"}['href']` probably.  The `{}` are necessary because of the `@` in the property name.